# Error while trying to save an image in background in Xcode and Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-ios-sdk

I am trying to save an image on the Parse server launched with AWS. when I push the postImage button i see the following error message:

> "The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the right format"

. My `Xcode` version is `10.2.1`

If I save the data without the image file is working, the class is created on the parse server and both the comment and the user objectIds are added.

This is the code in the button:

```
@IBOutlet weak var comment: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var imageToPost: UIImageView!

@IBAction func postImage(_ sender: Any) {
     if let image = imageToPost.image {

     // Create the class object for the Post
     let post = PFObject(className: "Post")
     post["Message"] = comment.text
     post["userId"] = PFUser.current()?.objectId

        // Create the image data
        if let imageData = image.pngData() {
            let imageFile = PFFileObject(name: "image.png", data: imageData)
            post["imageFile"] = imageFile
            post.saveInBackground { (success, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("There were issues saving the file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    self.displayAlert(title: "Error", message: "Image could not be posted, please try again later")
                } else {
                    // SAving successful
                    print("File saved correctly")
                    self.displayAlert(title: "Image Posted", message: "Your image hase posted successfully")
                    self.comment.text = ""
                    self.imageToPost.image = nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I would expect that the class is created with the comment, userId and the image file. But the class is not even created as it goes directly in the error management

Comment: It may be related to your Parse Server configuration - see [this issue](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/3532).

Comment: Thanks! The issue is on the server side indeed with the max upload size of 20mb... If i `print(imageData)` it says is 28MB... If I convert to jpg instead using `image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3)` then the imaged is saved to the server

Comment: Great, you should also be able to change the max upload size on your parse server configuration if necessary.

Comment: Could you post an answer on this question for anyone with a similar issue and mark it as solved.